# Delete of empty shared drive fails

Tags: google-drive-api

Trying to delete [1] a shared drive. The request returns with 403 Forbidden
and the following body:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "cannotDeleteResourceWithChildren",
    "message": "This resource cannot be deleted because it has children."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "This resource cannot be deleted because it has children."
 }
}
```

The drive is however empty. An immediate previous list request returned an empty list.

Issuing the same delete request again after a few seconds is successful.

Edit: forgot to mention a file was deleted (sent to trash) just before the list request.

The steps to reproduce are:

- send a file under the shared drive to trash;
- list request. It returns an empty list;
- delete shared drive request

[1] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/delete

[2] https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list

Edit: I'm able to reproduce this problem using cURL. The cURL entries were created with Copy as cURL from Chrome. See below the bash script followed by its output. It is a shared drive with 10 files.

```
DRIVEID=0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA

curl "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=drive&driveId=$DRIVEID&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&q=trashed%3Dfalse&supportsAllDrives=true&fields=files(id%2Cname)" -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'x-goog-encode-response-if-executable: base64' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'authorization: Bearer AuthToken0' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'x-clientdetails: appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1' -H 'x-javascript-user-agent: apix/3.0.0 google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3829.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/77.0.197.1' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.pt_BR.9VS-OXqJJxY.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOat2vY5WjTVOTl0GbC_09htXr7UQ%2Fm%3D__features__' -H 'authority: content.googleapis.com' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'x-referer: https://explorer.apis.google.com' --compressed

curl 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1fkLANZMuX7Tl_6rTQgqFV6x2St48UcVo?supportsAllDrives=true&alt=json' -X PATCH -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'x-goog-encode-response-if-executable: base64' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'authorization: Bearer AuthToken' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'x-clientdetails: appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3829.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/77.0.197.1' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.pt_BR.9VS-OXqJJxY.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOat2vY5WjTVOTl0GbC_09htXr7UQ%2Fm%3D__features__' -H 'authority: content.googleapis.com' -H 'x-javascript-user-agent: apix/3.0.0 google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0' -H 'x-referer: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'origin: https://content.googleapis.com' --data-binary '{"trashed":true}' --compressed
curl 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1dVyvc8x9hqRSG81gbzH7QlXdy9pVPOpF?supportsAllDrives=true&alt=json' -X PATCH -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'x-goog-encode-response-if-executable: base64' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'authorization: Bearer AuthToken' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'x-clientdetails: appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3829.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/77.0.197.1' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.pt_BR.9VS-OXqJJxY.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOat2vY5WjTVOTl0GbC_09htXr7UQ%2Fm%3D__features__' -H 'authority: content.googleapis.com' -H 'x-javascript-user-agent: apix/3.0.0 google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0' -H 'x-referer: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'origin: https://content.googleapis.com' --data-binary '{"trashed":true}' --compressed
curl 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1XNte7tA6g95YOdM4Kfrr-YWs3-c6WtOZ?supportsAllDrives=true&alt=json' -X PATCH -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'x-goog-encode-response-if-executable: base64' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'authorization: Bearer AuthToken' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'x-clientdetails: appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3829.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/77.0.197.1' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.pt_BR.9VS-OXqJJxY.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOat2vY5WjTVOTl0GbC_09htXr7UQ%2Fm%3D__features__' -H 'authority: content.googleapis.com' -H 'x-javascript-user-agent: apix/3.0.0 google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0' -H 'x-referer: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'origin: https://content.googleapis.com' --data-binary '{"trashed":true}' --compressed
curl 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1pQ52Qya4qv9TzvV4MxnXcXZBzlbsc3Ky?supportsAllDrives=true&alt=json' -X PATCH -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'x-goog-encode-response-if-executable: base64' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'authorization: Bearer AuthToken' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'x-clientdetails: appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3829.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/77.0.197.1' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.pt_BR.9VS-OXqJJxY.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOat2vY5WjTVOTl0GbC_09htXr7UQ%2Fm%3D__features__' -H 'authority: content.googleapis.com' -H 'x-javascript-user-agent: apix/3.0.0 google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0' -H 'x-referer: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'origin: https://content.googleapis.com' --data-binary '{"trashed":true}' --compressed
curl 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1ymmxdvHlqZTggK2H5WxAYLYMTwwmh-26?supportsAllDrives=true&alt=json' -X PATCH -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'x-goog-encode-response-if-executable: base64' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'authorization: Bearer AuthToken' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'x-clientdetails: appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3829.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/77.0.197.1' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.pt_BR.9VS-OXqJJxY.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOat2vY5WjTVOTl0GbC_09htXr7UQ%2Fm%3D__features__' -H 'authority: content.googleapis.com' -H 'x-javascript-user-agent: apix/3.0.0 google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0' -H 'x-referer: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'origin: https://content.googleapis.com' --data-binary '{"trashed":true}' --compressed
curl 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1fhwOPeobj_1MRo_eaY-c_MQ2B44LVc3Z?supportsAllDrives=true&alt=json' -X PATCH -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'x-goog-encode-response-if-executable: base64' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'authorization: Bearer AuthToken' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'x-clientdetails: appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3829.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/77.0.197.1' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.pt_BR.9VS-OXqJJxY.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOat2vY5WjTVOTl0GbC_09htXr7UQ%2Fm%3D__features__' -H 'authority: content.googleapis.com' -H 'x-javascript-user-agent: apix/3.0.0 google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0' -H 'x-referer: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'origin: https://content.googleapis.com' --data-binary '{"trashed":true}' --compressed
curl 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1st_wpikySnsAdikUDePGqbo4bDQTEynl?supportsAllDrives=true&alt=json' -X PATCH -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'x-goog-encode-response-if-executable: base64' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'authorization: Bearer AuthToken' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'x-clientdetails: appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3829.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/77.0.197.1' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.pt_BR.9VS-OXqJJxY.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOat2vY5WjTVOTl0GbC_09htXr7UQ%2Fm%3D__features__' -H 'authority: content.googleapis.com' -H 'x-javascript-user-agent: apix/3.0.0 google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0' -H 'x-referer: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'origin: https://content.googleapis.com' --data-binary '{"trashed":true}' --compressed
curl 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1xKpaojPrgqcwWgwCbWse2KGgVwjC7SaW?supportsAllDrives=true&alt=json' -X PATCH -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'x-goog-encode-response-if-executable: base64' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'authorization: Bearer AuthToken' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'x-clientdetails: appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3829.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/77.0.197.1' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.pt_BR.9VS-OXqJJxY.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOat2vY5WjTVOTl0GbC_09htXr7UQ%2Fm%3D__features__' -H 'authority: content.googleapis.com' -H 'x-javascript-user-agent: apix/3.0.0 google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0' -H 'x-referer: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'origin: https://content.googleapis.com' --data-binary '{"trashed":true}' --compressed
curl 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1btL_jLjrUg3oO3y2275lcq2T5VxmESuM?supportsAllDrives=true&alt=json' -X PATCH -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'x-goog-encode-response-if-executable: base64' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'authorization: Bearer AuthToken' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'x-clientdetails: appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3829.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/77.0.197.1' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.pt_BR.9VS-OXqJJxY.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOat2vY5WjTVOTl0GbC_09htXr7UQ%2Fm%3D__features__' -H 'authority: content.googleapis.com' -H 'x-javascript-user-agent: apix/3.0.0 google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0' -H 'x-referer: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'origin: https://content.googleapis.com' --data-binary '{"trashed":true}' --compressed
curl 'https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/1TBypd04jm7s3gVo0fc61hs4Gx7Uo4E0Y?supportsAllDrives=true&alt=json' -X PATCH -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'x-goog-encode-response-if-executable: base64' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'authorization: Bearer AuthToken' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'x-clientdetails: appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3829.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/77.0.197.1' -H 'content-type: application/json' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.pt_BR.9VS-OXqJJxY.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOat2vY5WjTVOTl0GbC_09htXr7UQ%2Fm%3D__features__' -H 'authority: content.googleapis.com' -H 'x-javascript-user-agent: apix/3.0.0 google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0' -H 'x-referer: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'origin: https://content.googleapis.com' --data-binary '{"trashed":true}' --compressed

curl "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=drive&driveId=$DRIVEID&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&q=trashed%3Dfalse&supportsAllDrives=true&fields=files(id%2Cname)" -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'x-goog-encode-response-if-executable: base64' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'authorization: Bearer AuthToken2' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'x-clientdetails: appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1' -H 'x-javascript-user-agent: apix/3.0.0 google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3829.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/77.0.197.1' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.pt_BR.9VS-OXqJJxY.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOat2vY5WjTVOTl0GbC_09htXr7UQ%2Fm%3D__features__' -H 'authority: content.googleapis.com' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'x-referer: https://explorer.apis.google.com' --compressed

curl "https://content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives/$DRIVEID" -X DELETE -H 'sec-fetch-mode: cors' -H 'x-goog-encode-response-if-executable: base64' -H 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'x-origin: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9' -H 'authorization: Bearer AuthToken3' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'x-clientdetails: appVersion=5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1&platform=Win32&userAgent=Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F77.0.3829.0%20Safari%2F537.36%20Edg%2F77.0.197.1' -H 'x-javascript-user-agent: apix/3.0.0 google-api-javascript-client/1.1.0' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3829.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/77.0.197.1' -H 'accept: */*' -H 'referer: https://content.googleapis.com/static/proxy.html?usegapi=1&jsh=m%3B%2F_%2Fscs%2Fapps-static%2F_%2Fjs%2Fk%3Doz.gapi.pt_BR.9VS-OXqJJxY.O%2Fam%3DwQE%2Fd%3D1%2Frs%3DAGLTcCOat2vY5WjTVOTl0GbC_09htXr7UQ%2Fm%3D__features__' -H 'authority: content.googleapis.com' -H 'sec-fetch-site: same-origin' -H 'x-referer: https://explorer.apis.google.com' -H 'origin: https://content.googleapis.com' --compressed
```

This is the output

```
{
 "files": [
  {
   "id": "1fkLANZMuX7Tl_6rTQgqFV6x2St48UcVo",
   "name": "file-0010"
  },
  {
   "id": "1dVyvc8x9hqRSG81gbzH7QlXdy9pVPOpF",
   "name": "file-0005"
  },
  {
   "id": "1XNte7tA6g95YOdM4Kfrr-YWs3-c6WtOZ",
   "name": "file-0004"
  },
  {
   "id": "1pQ52Qya4qv9TzvV4MxnXcXZBzlbsc3Ky",
   "name": "file-0002"
  },
  {
   "id": "1ymmxdvHlqZTggK2H5WxAYLYMTwwmh-26",
   "name": "file-0003"
  },
  {
   "id": "1fhwOPeobj_1MRo_eaY-c_MQ2B44LVc3Z",
   "name": "file-0001"
  },
  {
   "id": "1st_wpikySnsAdikUDePGqbo4bDQTEynl",
   "name": "file-0008"
  },
  {
   "id": "1xKpaojPrgqcwWgwCbWse2KGgVwjC7SaW",
   "name": "file-0007"
  },
  {
   "id": "1btL_jLjrUg3oO3y2275lcq2T5VxmESuM",
   "name": "file-0006"
  },
  {
   "id": "1TBypd04jm7s3gVo0fc61hs4Gx7Uo4E0Y",
   "name": "file-0009"
  }
 ]
}
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1fkLANZMuX7Tl_6rTQgqFV6x2St48UcVo",
 "name": "file-0010",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
 "teamDriveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA",
 "driveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA"
}
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1dVyvc8x9hqRSG81gbzH7QlXdy9pVPOpF",
 "name": "file-0005",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
 "teamDriveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA",
 "driveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA"
}
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1XNte7tA6g95YOdM4Kfrr-YWs3-c6WtOZ",
 "name": "file-0004",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
 "teamDriveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA",
 "driveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA"
}
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1pQ52Qya4qv9TzvV4MxnXcXZBzlbsc3Ky",
 "name": "file-0002",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
 "teamDriveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA",
 "driveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA"
}
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1ymmxdvHlqZTggK2H5WxAYLYMTwwmh-26",
 "name": "file-0003",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
 "teamDriveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA",
 "driveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA"
}
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1fhwOPeobj_1MRo_eaY-c_MQ2B44LVc3Z",
 "name": "file-0001",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
 "teamDriveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA",
 "driveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA"
}
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1st_wpikySnsAdikUDePGqbo4bDQTEynl",
 "name": "file-0008",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
 "teamDriveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA",
 "driveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA"
}
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1xKpaojPrgqcwWgwCbWse2KGgVwjC7SaW",
 "name": "file-0007",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
 "teamDriveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA",
 "driveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA"
}
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1btL_jLjrUg3oO3y2275lcq2T5VxmESuM",
 "name": "file-0006",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
 "teamDriveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA",
 "driveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA"
}
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": "1TBypd04jm7s3gVo0fc61hs4Gx7Uo4E0Y",
 "name": "file-0009",
 "mimeType": "application/octet-stream",
 "teamDriveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA",
 "driveId": "0ANMOBifriUr9Uk9PVA"
}
{
 "files": []
}
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "cannotDeleteResourceWithChildren",
    "message": "This resource cannot be deleted because it has children."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "This resource cannot be deleted because it has children."
 }
}
```

Of special interest are the two last responses: [2] returns an empty list

```
{
 "files": []
}
```

But [1] gives the error.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "cannotDeleteResourceWithChildren",
    "message": "This resource cannot be deleted because it has children."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "This resource cannot be deleted because it has children."
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share the code you have tried to do this?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo Unfortunately not. The source is closed. But I was able to reproduce it using cURL.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that when you trash a file, it is still linked to the Drive that it was trashed from so that if you need, it can be recovered at a later date. Simply updating the `trashed` property to `True` doesn't remove the link between the file and the parent drive.

There are a couple of things you can do here - you can either trash the file and then change the parents linked using [`Files: update`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update), making sure that you use the following parameters:

```
fileId = 'ID of file'
supportsAllDrives = True
addParents = 'Drive ID of different Drive'
removeParents = 'ID of Shared Drive you want to delete'
```

A file has to have at least one parent link so adding a new link needs to be done before removing the shared Drive link.

The other option is to delete the file directly instead of sending it to the trash - only do this if you're sure you don't have to recover the file though as it can't be recovered when done this way. This is done using the [`Files: delete()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/delete) method, again you will need to use the following parameters:

```
fileId = 'ID of file'
supportsAllDrives = True
```

Allowing you to then delete the drive with the [`Drives: delete()`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/drives/delete) method.